# Post Format Link Validation Error

Tags: the-content, post-formats, validation

For link post formats to appear in my archive.php I'm using the following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 100 ); ?>">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</a>
```

**Of course, this creates a validation error due to a `<p>` being inside an `<a>`.  I'm seeking a solution to fix this validation error.**

This is the most intuitive way I can dream up for easy link post formats (of course, I'm open to suggestions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily remove the filter that adds paragraph tags:

```
// remove the filter
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

// output content
the_content();

// add the filter again
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a satisfying solution.

Comment: @siouxfan45 perhaps elaborate on why it's not?

Comment: If put in functions.php, this will remove the <p> tag from all occurrences of the_content.  I'm seeking to remove it in this one scenario.

Comment: @siouxfan45 which is why above I remove the filter, output the content, then immediately re-add the filter. this would go directly in your template where you want the content to appear without p tags, not in functions.php